# ¿Porqué no puedo hacer SUM a una sentencia CASE?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Estoy creando una nueva consulta (*query*) para obtener la suma de las cantidades de ingreso y salida de un almacén. Lo primero que he hecho es formular una consulta que me permite separar las entradas de las salidas colocándoles un signo `-` delante de la cantidad cuando es ingreso, eso lo he hecho con un `case when`:

```
select productoid, descripcion, codigodelproveedor, marcacodigo, modelo, codigopropio, 
       case tipooperacion when 'S' then cantidad when 'I' then cantidad * -1 end as cantidad 
from ViewParteDeAlmacenProductosDescriptivo
```

Ahora lo que necesito es hacer un `sum` con el resultado del `case` pero estoy recibiendo el siguiente error:

> Msg 195, Level 15, State 10, Line 2
>       'sum' is not a recognized built-in function name.

Ésta es la nueva consulta:

```
select productoid, descripcion, codigodelproveedor, marcacodigo, modelo, codigopropio, 
       sum(case tipooperacion when 'S' then cantidad when 'I' then cantidad * -1 end as cantidad) as cantidad 
from ViewParteDeAlmacenProductosDescriptivo 
group by productoid, descripcion, codigodelproveedor, marcacodigo, modelo, codigopropio
```

¿Alguna idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Prueba a quitarle el as cantidad dentro del sum, también le he cambiado el nombre a la variable cantidad externa para que no coincida con la que utilizas dentro, por si acaso:

```
select productoid, descripcion, codigodelproveedor, marcacodigo, modelo, codigopropio, 
       sum(case tipooperacion when 'S' then cantidad when 'I' then cantidad * -1 end ) as cantidad1 
from ViewParteDeAlmacenProductosDescriptivo 
group by productoid, descripcion, codigodelproveedor, marcacodigo, modelo, codigopropio
```

Comment: Muchas gracias!!!, no pense que el error era por tener luego del cierre del comando `case` un `as cantidad` que se cruzaba con el otro `as cantidad` del comando `sum`. Cosas que uno va aprendiendo.

Answer (score 1):

Creo que el tema pasa por colocar la función **SUM** dentro de cada case, el ***as*** no tendría problemas:

```
SELECT productoid, descripcion, codigodelproveedor, 
       marcacodigo, modelo, codigopropio, 
       CASE tipooperacion 
            WHEN 'S' THEN
                SUM(cantidad) 
            WHEN 'I' THEN 
                SUM(cantidad * -1) 
       AS cantidad 
       FROM ViewParteDeAlmacenProductosDescriptivo 
       GROUP BY productoid, descripcion, codigodelproveedor, 
                marcacodigo, modelo, codigopropio
```

De esta manera calculará la sumatoria de las cantidades según el **case**.